# How to sticky 2 table rows of the first table when scrolling to another table?(css)

Tags: css

How can I maintain the first 2 rows of a table sticky(the red one and the blue one) sticky, even after I am with the scroll at the second table. Thank you! I will appreciate any help. I attached the code and the link to jsfiddle.

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0z6kybrh/32/

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table:first-of-type thead tr,
table:first-of-type tbody tr:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 1;
}

table:first-of-type thead tr {
  background: red;
}

table:first-of-type tbody tr:first-child {
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table:nth-child(4) {
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>one table</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h1>another table</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>{" "}
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sticky, try with the position:fixed property.

An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.

```css
.wrapper h1 {
  margin: 20px 0 75px 0;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table:first-of-type thead tr,
table:first-of-type tbody tr:first-child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 1;
}

table:first-of-type thead tr {
  background: red;
}

table:first-of-type tbody tr:first-child {
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 105px;
  z-index: 1;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table:nth-child(4) {
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>one table</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h1>another table</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>{" "}
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>;
```

Comment: i will try to implement with fixed as you write above, if it's a solution with sticky, can i use sticky for this? with fixed i have to do a lot of modifications in my current code

Comment: you can paste the same thead in 2nd table or apply same properties to the 2nd thead